# Trying to manage DNS records of GoDaddy Domain Name on 123-reg

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy

I have a domain name registered with GoDaddy. I have hosting with 123-reg. I have the A record of the domain name set to point to my server at 123-reg. Now I want to manage my DNS settings through my 123-reg account. How do I do this? I've just changed the NS records of my domain name to point to 123-reg's nameservers, but I'm unsure if that will automatically make my domain name appear there?!

Does anyone know if what I'm doing is right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You manage the DNS wherever the nameservers are pointing.

If you have changed it to 123-reg, then that is where you will make DNS changes, assuming you have an account with 123-reg and the domain is added to their system so there is a zone file.

You may have to be patient to wait for propagation to complete but it usually take 2 - 4 hours or so.